# JAVA - How do I detect "\n" characters from a scanner reading from a file

Tags: java

First time poster,

I'm having trouble reading a return character from a scanner reading through a text file.

The text file being read from looks like this:

```
//test.txt start//

2

0 30 30 1

1 90 30 0

//test.txt end//
```

First Line: 2 (indicating two points)

Second Line: position index: 0 xpos: 30 ypos: 30 draw line to position 1

Third Line: position index: 1 xpos: 90 ypos: 30 draw line to position 0

I know the code change should go in this do/while.

```
do {        
    edge[pNum].add(input.nextInt());
} while(input.hasNextInt());
```

The rest of the code seems to function as intended, but I can't seem to detect the `"\n"` return characters from the text file in order to save the x,y values in the position array and the following values in the ArrayList and start the process over for the next line in the text file.

Here's the full code below:

```
public class PointReader extends JFrame {

    class GraphView extends JPanel{

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String fileName;

        System.out.print("Input File Name: ");
        Scanner user = new Scanner( System.in ); 
        fileName = user.nextLine();

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int count = input.nextInt();

        int[][] position = new int[count][2];
        ArrayList[] edge = new ArrayList[count];

        for(int k = 0; k < edge.length; k++){
            edge[k] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        while(input.hasNextInt()){

            int pNum = input.nextInt();
            int xPos = input.nextInt();
            int yPos = input.nextInt();

            position[pNum][0] = xPos;
            position[pNum][1] = yPos;

            do{        
                edge[pNum].add(input.nextInt());
            }while(input.hasNextInt());
        }

        System.out.println(count);

        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
            System.out.println(i + " " + position[i][0] + " " + position[i][1] + " ");

            for(int j = 0; j < edge[i].size(); j++){
                System.out.print(edge[i].get(j) + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `while(!(input.next().equals("\n")));` and it's still not being detected. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your reading logic is correct? Given the (minimal) example, I would think `pNum` indicates the number of sets of 4 numbers, and so all you need to do is read 4 `nextInt`s in a loop over `pNum` instead of a `while`.

Comment: Another file for testing these values is as follows:
// test2.txt //
7 \n
0 50 45 1 3 4 \n 
1 150 25 0 2 3 5 \n 
2 250 155 1 4 6 \n
3 150 155 0 1 4 \n
4 30 255 0 2 3 6 \n
5 270 55 1 6 \n
6 60 95 2 4 5 \n
// end file //

So the file is saying "7" points (first line)
Every other line starts with the index of the positions array, then the x, y positions, followed by the other indexes of points that have a line draw from the initial index. The final result should be seven points with various lines drawn to other points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to seperate the file into lines, the easiest way is probably to process each line individually.

```
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = input.nextLine();

    // DO STUFF WITH LINE...
}
```

So you get each line into the String "line" and can do something with it then, and you dont have to take care of seperating the lines yourself. 
But other than that, I am not hundred percent sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. I sometimes over-complicate things when I'm working on something for too long.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a new line character is treated as white space.

You can manually set the delimiter of the Scanner:

```
scanner = new Scanner(...).useDelimiter(" "); //To use only space as a delimiter.
```

This will make line feeds appear as tokens which will be returned by `scanner.next();`

The changes that you suggested to your code should now work.

Comment: So in this case, the user would likely want to set the Delimiter to ```("\n")``` right?

Comment: If you wanted to use `"\n"` as the delimiter then @flotothemoon's answer would be better. Using `" "` as the delimiter fits the original question, but not the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using input.nextLine() to grab the rest of the values and then toss those through another scanner thanks to L33D's suggestion:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            int count = input.nextInt();

            int[][] position = new int[count][2];
            ArrayList[] edge = new ArrayList[count];

        for(int k = 0; k < edge.length; k++){
            edge[k] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

         while(input.hasNext()){

            int pNum = input.nextInt();
            int xPos = input.nextInt();
            int yPos = input.nextInt();

            position[pNum][0] = xPos;
            position[pNum][1] = yPos;

            String extra = input.nextLine();
            Scanner linescan = new Scanner(extra);

            while(linescan.hasNextInt()){
                edge[pNum].add(linescan.nextInt());
            }
        }
```

Then is code displays the file read:

```
// displays input read from file
        System.out.println("File input from file: ");
        System.out.println(count);

        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
            System.out.print(i + " " + position[i][0] + " " + position[i][1] + " ");

            for(int j = 0; j < edge[i].size(); j++){
                System.out.print(edge[i].get(j) + " ");
            }

        System.out.println();
        }
```

and finally the graphing code is as follows:

```
// draws points, edges, and finally labels points
        int pointName = 0;

        for(int h = 0; h < count; h++){

            g.fillOval(position[h][0], position[h][1], 10, 10);

            for(int y = 0; y < edge[h].size(); y++){
                int ref = (int)edge[h].get(y);
                g.drawLine((position[h][0] + 5), (position[h][1] + 5), (position[ref][0] + 5), (position[ref][1]+ 5));
            }
            if(((h % 2) == 0)){
                g.drawString(" " + pointName+ " ", (position[h][0] - 15), (position[h][1] + 10));
            }
            else{
                g.drawString(" " + pointName + " ", (position[h][0] + 15), (position[h][1] + 10));
            }
            pointName++;
        }
```