# Is there a way for Java Scanner to include '\n' when it is reading lines?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there any way for `java.util.Scanner` to include the newline escape character when reading from a file?

This is my code:

```
File myFile = new File("file.txt");
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
String content = "";
while(myReader.hasNextLine()) {

    content += myReader.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(content);
myReader.close();
```

When it reads from the file, it doesn't include '\n' or any new lines. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just append `\n` character to a variable after reading a line. If you really want to read as-is then use `nextByte()` function.

Comment: This subject was answered here ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312161/java-how-do-i-detect-n-characters-from-a-scanner-reading-from-a-file

Comment: @manuelantunes - No, it hasn't been answered there. That question is: `How do I detect “\n” characters from a scanner reading from a file` whereas this question is: `Is there a way for Java Scanner to include '\n' when it is reading lines?`

Comment: There is no "newline escape character", unless you're referring to the "\" in a string literal. Once a "\n" inside a string literal has been processed, there is only the newline character, and the "\n" sequence is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When it reads from the file, it doesn't include '\n' or any new lines.
> Does anyone know how to do this?

You can add the new line explicitly as follows:

```
while(myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    content += myReader.nextLine() + "\n";
}
```

I also recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for appending in a loop.

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    content.append(myReader.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
    // or the following
    // content.append(myReader.nextLine()).append('\n');
}
```

Check [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you you just want to read in lines and the line terminator you can do it by changing the behavior of `Scanner.next()`. If you run the following it will take in the line and the new line terminator as one unit.

- `\\z` is a regex directive that says to include the line terminator.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter("\\z");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String line = scan.next();
    System.out.println(line + "on next line");
}
```

To read from a file, try this.

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("f:/Datafile.txt"));
    scan.useDelimiter("\\z");
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.next();
        System.out.print(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
    fe.printStackTrace();
}
```